# Cities Skylines crashing on Wine/PlayonLinux

Tags: wine, 19.04, playonlinux

When I launch Cities Skylines Campus it loads just fine but once I click to create a new map, it gets like 75% through loading and then just disappears. Any ideas or advice? I'm still new to Linux but I run other programs through PlayonLinux just fine.

Thank you!

Comment: The Steam page for Cities Skylines says that it runs on Linux -- why use Wine or any other emulatior or VM if you can run it natively?  Wine should be the avenue of last resort.

Comment: I have a Windows ISO of it and I can't seem to figure out how to install it on Steam :/

Comment: the package `steam` is available in `multiverse` repositories.  You should be able to easily install it through `apt` or through the software center.  Once Steam is installed, even if you did not buy the game from Steam, you can [activate](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352) your copy.  Of course you need a legitimate licensed copy, since the game is not copyleft software

Comment: @Nmath When I'm in Steam it'll say, "Install a non-Steam program" and it's not in the list. I've tried selecting like the .exe of it and it won't launch. Every thing I tried doesn't work through Steam. I even tried installing with Wine and adding it in Steam but it won't launch. And right clicking and pressing to launch in Steam doesn't do anything. Doesn't even launch Steam.

Comment: @Nmath I did follow your link. I don't have the product key, all I have is an .iso file. Otherwise I naturally would have added it that way.